# Is there any way to dedicate cpu cores exclusively for a process in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, process, cpu, multicore, affinity

I want to dedicate some cpu cores exclusively for my real-time data streaming application because I want to ensure that this process is always running without context-switching. (Ensuring no application except my process running on that core)

It seems there's a working solution for Linux. Is there any way to do this for Windows 10?

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

(I've thought about setting process affinity in task manager. 
But to dedicate cpu cores(for example only core 1) exclusively for my process, I have to uncheck core 1 in process affinity window for all processes, and only check core 1 for my process. 
However, this solution is too tedious physical labor and seems hard to do it programmatically.)

Comment: No, Windows does not provide any way to do this.  What you *can* do is increase your thread's priority.  There will always be some lost time, though, from hardware interrupts if nothing else.  Windows is not a real-time operating system.

Comment: Have you run into any issues while having the task scheduler operate as designed, or are you looking into premature optimization?

Comment: @IInspectable Actually it's premature optimization. I'm just looking for the best way I can do for my app.

Comment: The best way is to not do anything at all, unless there is a verifiable reason. The OS is written by professionals, with feedback from users running the most diverse collection of software, over several decades. Unless you have very unique requirements, the OS will do just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WIN32 API SetProcessAffinityMask() to set process affinity.

Comment: That controls, which core a process' threads run on. It doesn't mark this core for exclusive use by a single process, as the question asked for.

Comment: @IInspectable You can use SetProcessAffinityMask() to do what the OP described in his final comment. Ie. Using EnumerateProcesses(), and call SetProcessAffinityMask() for every process in the system. Not elegant & probably requires admin privileges. However it would do exactly what the OP described as "hard to do programatically".

Comment: What about processes that get created after your code ran? What about the obvious TOCTTOU race? What about system services, or driver code? Sorry, this isn't even a theoretical possibility.

Comment: I was simply describing a way to achieve what the OP said he was doing in task manager. I agree it's not perect.

Comment: Not being perfect somehow doesn't quite address the fact, that it's impossible. Anyway, I voted on this answer, there's not much point in reiterating the reasons for doing so.